# Doxygen. How can I exclude more than one file?

Tags: doxygen

In my configuration file where

`EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded`

and it works fine, but if I want to exclude more files, there is no way.
I have tried:

`EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded
          ./fileToBeExcluded2`

`EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded,
          ./fileToBeExcluded2`

`EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded
 EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded2`

Any suggestions??
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to use the backSlash "\"

`EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded \
          ./fileToBeExcluded2`

and that works.

Comment: As with all the other config options, multiple values are to be separated by spaces (e.g. `EXCLUDE = ./fileToBeExcluded ./fileToBeExcluded2` ). Backslash just connects the lines.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the += possibility of the keys